# Is it possible to get free personal chess coaching?

Tags: learning, training, development, coach

I am a young 1300 fide rated chess player and in my surrounding it's difficult to find a good chess coach. I play 1-3 fide rated tournaments every year and I see improvements every time. But I thought that I could double this improvement rate if I can find the perfect chess mentor for me.

I am a student and don't have a proper idea about how to balance my studies and chess. Hence I decided to find someone who could help me and went to chatgpt for help. It said that on this website I can find someone who will be willing to help me to get better at handling chess and studies and also help me get better at chess just because they want to help me.

I hope to find that person soon.

Comment: If you're actually promising someone may accept to coach you in exchange for prize money or playing for free on a certain team, but as a 1300 player I highly doubt it

Comment: What do you mean by playing for free on a certain team?

Comment: In some tournaments players play in teams. Some of those teams will offer money to their strongest players to pay for them

Comment: Why do you want FREE chess coaching? Pay for a reputable coach instead.

Answer (score 7):

This site isn't a brokerage for free personal chess coaching.
This is a QA site, where you can ask chess-related questions.

That means, that if you have a position that you don't understand, are looking for training materials (e.g. books, video courses, ...) on certain chess topics, or have any other question that will improve your game, we're happy to help. This is how we can help your chess development.

If you're looking for affordable personal trainers that meet with you online (or in person), I recommend you to check trainers registered on [lichess](https://lichess.org/coach/all/all/login)
and [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/coaches).

You can find affordable trainers online, especially ones from non-western countries with lower wages. The price will be higher if you only speak English, German, Dutch or another language spoken predominantly in rich countires. You can find very affordable trainers (5-15$/h) from middle and south america if you're willing to take your lessons in Spanish, for example.
Of course, stronger and more experienced coaches will be more expensive.

If you're not willing to spend any money, it's unlikely that you'll find a coach with a decent playing strength. In this case, you have plenty of options to learn chess for free. There are countless free lessons that you can watch on YouTube, as well as complete chess courses that are free, e.g. on [ChessFactor](https://www.chessfactor.com/instructors/).

Comment: Never heard of that before but I will try chessfactor. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 3):

This is not the place for free personal chess coaching. If you are serious about improving your chess but not serious enough to pay a coach then your best bet is to join a local chess club and play over the board on a weekly basis. Such clubs will often provide free coaching to juniors like yourself. That will almost certainly be in groups but you may get lucky.

I would add that I don't think anybody is going to want to give free chess lessons to somebody who identifies as a Chess GM.

Comment: Ya I will consider that

Answer (score 0):

I’m rated 2000 rapid on chess.com if you need help improving I got you bro free of charge message me on chess.com my user name is -bishopiscoming